# Is a service a model in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, service, model, view, controllers

I create a project structure of a web-app with angular.
I create my directories with services, controllers and views.
Then, my team ask me: where are the models? (Nobody of us have worked with angular)
And I answered that in the service, because is where the data persist.
But Im no really sure, and I cant find useful info about this.

Comment: The models (as in MVC) can be POJO or everything you want in Angular. Services are just DI entities that can be every JS type you want. So basically, yes.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a factory provider. You can create a factory with a collection inside, and this "class" has operations to handle the collection and sincronize it with the back-end.

See this example:
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket/blob/master/README.md

You can see how to create a collection and initialize it with data that comes from a websocket.
Aditionally you can create operations to handle the collection

This could be consider a "model" in angular.

Answer (score 1):

It is a best practice to keep business logic in Services (and not in controllers, for example). This is, among other reasons, because controllers are instantiated for each view and Services are singeltons.

You can refer to those great posts for more details:

https://johnpapa.net/sharing-data-in-an-angular-controller-or-an-angular-service/

http://teropa.info/blog/2014/10/24/how-ive-improved-my-angular-apps-by-banning-ng-controller.html

https://toddmotto.com/rethinking-angular-js-controllers/

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume from the verbiage you've used that you're referring to Angular 1.x.

Services are typically used **by controllers** to pull data from a provider not displayed in the view. The provider can be a public api, a static file on your own server, a mongo database, etc.

A model for a controller represents the data being manipulated between the view and the controller (refer to `ngModel`).